# Fetch particular username from JSON array and Display in BOT interface

Tags: json, api, azure-bot-service, site24x7

I am able to call site24x7api to fetch all the customers details (E.g user_id, name, zaaid) in terminal with the help of .js file

INPUT :

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json; version=2.0',
    'Authorization': 'Zoho-authtoken xxx12sdc231xx'
};

var options = {
    url: 'https://www.site24x7.com/api/short/msp/customers',
    headers: headers
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

OUTPUT(In terminal) :

```
{
"user_id":"12345678912123",
"name":"abc",
"zaaid":"12341234"
},
{
"user_id":"98123141231233",
"name":"Xyz",
"zaaid":"43241123"
} ... and many more
```

Now suppose, BOT asks user for name and user enter name as

> abc

The program should match the name which user enters (stored in `'${session.dialogData.Companyname}'` ) and the name present in the terminal and BOT should return the zaaid(int) or user_id(int) related to that particular user that is 12341234 in this  case to the BOT interface

I've tried

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377220/i-want-get-one-specific-entry-from-json-data-array-and-do-some-modification)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627706/selecting-a-specific-item-in-json-array)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Array to loop through your json file, For Example:

```
var users = [{
"user_id":"12345678912123",
"name":"abc",
"zaaid":"12341234"
},
{
"user_id":"98123141231233",
"name":"Xyz",
"zaaid":"43241123"
}]

for (i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
  if (users[i].name = "the_name") {
    do_something....
  }
}
```